# Needing to restart Wamp Server repeatedly?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, reboot, wamp

Wamp server is constantly showing as "server Online" but after every five minutes localhost and phpadmin stop working i.e., they keep loading and never open.

What's wrong?

I am using Wamp server on a Windows 8 with google chrome and my programs contains only HTML and PHP.

Comment: You are using IE right?

Comment: @c0dev No, Google chrome

Comment: Okay. I'd still recommend you to try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutting the Proxy Settings off, solved the problem.

Comment: What proxy settings are you turning off? Can you explain better? TQ.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the [mpm_winnt_module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/da/mod/mpm_winnt.html) at windows.
You can easily fix this issue by editing your `httpd.conf`-file

1. Go to the httpd.conf-file

   > C:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.x.x\conf\httpd.conf
2. Open It and add the following lines:

   > #Stuck-fix
   >      AcceptFilter http none
   >      AcceptFilter https none
3. Restart the Server.

Now it should work.

*[Source](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=7920)*

**Update**

The source tells, that this should fix the problems in the IE, but possibly, it works also in chrome.